# T-test error 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: r

I am trying to do a t-test in r studio and I am getting this error:  error in match.arg(alternative) :'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
my code is:

```
install.packages("ggpubr")
library(ggpubr)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)
PHQ_Gender %>%
  select(PHQ_score, gender) %>%
t.test(PHQ_score ~ gender, PHQ_Gender)
```

the table looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVj5V.png)

My goal is to compare the mean values of genders and see whether the difference is significant.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your data, but it looks like you are over complicating things:

```r
t.test(PHQ_score ~ gender, data=PHQ_Gender)
```